# Design for an expensive custom event with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an expensive custom event (that is produced either by `MutationObserver` or by polling).
It is similar to http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/.

I want to only do observation/polling when there are subscribers to this event on a given element.

What is the right way to integrate with jQuery so I can get notified when my custom event is subscribed/unsubscribed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found a solution and it is pretty easy.
A minimal version is something like this:

```
$.event.special.myevent = {
    setup:    function() { expensiveObserve($(this));   },
    teardown: function() { expensiveUnobserve($(this)); },
    noBubble: true
};
```

See [jQuery Event Extensions](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/) for the full API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to do it...

A solution I can propose is to use a utility method to register/de-register the handler... something like

```
var MyUtils = (function () {
    var counter = 0;

    function handlerPresent() {
        //do somethig to fire the event
    }
    function handlerRemoved() {
        //do somethig to clear the firing
    }

    return {
        register: function (el, handler) {
            el.on('myevent', handler);
            counter++;
            if (counter == 1) {
                handlerPresent();
            }
        },
        deregister: function (el, handler) {
            el.off('myevent', handler);
            counter--;
            if (counter == 0) {
                handlerRemoved();
            }
        }

    }
})();
```